# internal process of proc mianalyze procedure

Tags: bias, sas, multiple-imputation, point-estimation, coverage-probability

Does proc mi analyze in sas consider only estimates of imputed values or complete data sets that is imputed values as well as non imputed values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROC MIANALYZE considers full data sets, including both imputed and nonimputed values.